# How to get distance between two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

So I have one div inside the other - how can I get distance between them?

[image: buttons]

I tried something like `$('#child').parentsUntil($('#parent')).andSelf()` - but it returns an object, not a distance.

P.S. I need it to push other buttons.

Comment: Try to test with `$("#child").position().left` and if needed subtract `$("#parent").position().left` from this value.

Answer (score 5):

http://api.jquery.com/position/

to get the left distance you can use:

```
var distLeft = $('#child').position().left;
```

**That will return the distance in `px` relative to the offset parent**

if you're interested into the element's page offset than:

```
var offsLeft = $('#child').offset().left;
```

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

```
  var childOffset = $('#child').offset(), parentOffset = $('#child').parentsUntil($('#parent')).offset();
    var leftDistance  =childOffset.left - parentOffset.left;
    var topDistance = childOffset.top- parentOffset.top;
```

Comment: `offset()` is IMHO the best solution, as it's even able to get the distance between two completely unrelated objects: `function distance(el1, el2) { var o1 = $(el1).offset(); var o2 = $(el2).offset(); return { left: o2.left - o1.left, top: o2.top - o1.top }; }`

Answer (score 2):

There's this awesome `getBoundingClientRect` function. Anything else is just `a-b`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like?

```
 $('innerDiv').position().left;
```